# Easier to read typescript type errors

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Is there a way (plugin or something) to get easier to read error messages in typesscript. I think it's hard to read when you get like {20+ props in here} can't be assigned to {20+ props in here too}

Sometimes when you work with normal JS files it just shows you the function all together which I think is more clear. I'll provide two images of what I think is hard to read and what I would prefer.

[Easy to read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhmXf.png)

[Hard to read, especially when there are more props than this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85Ek2.png)

Jerry

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, this is not possible.

The *Easy to read* screenshot is IntelliSense, and not part of TypeScript (and not an error!).

The *Hard to read ...* screenshot also has the *Easy to read* info (`import FamilyPrice`) but has an error.